# What does this sentence mean from "The Box Tunnel"?

Tags: british-english, writing, literature

I am reading a novel "The Box Tunnel" by Charles Reade. In the first paragraph, there is a sentence that I can't understand:

> The 10:15 train glided from Paddington May 7, 1847. In the left compartment of a certain first-class carriage were four passengers; of these two were worth description. The lady had a smooth, white, delicate brow, strongly marked eyebrows, long lashes, eyes that seemed to change colour, and a good-sized, delicious mouth, with teeth as white as milk. A man could not see her nose for her eyes and mouth; her own sex could, and would have told us some nonsense about it.

What's the meaning of "A man could not see her nose for her eyes and mouth; her own sex could, and would have told us some nonsense about it."?

Comment: Will likely be closed, but the point is that her eyes and mouth were so beautiful that no many would even notice her nose existed at all. Women might and they'd have some comment about it, but with eyes and a mouth like that, who cares?

Comment: Note that Box in 'Box tunnel' is a proper name (it is named for the village of Box). Legend has it that when IK Brunel drew up the plans for the London to Bristol section of the Great Western Railway he laid out that tunnel so that the rising sun would shine along its length on his birthday. A test was done on 9 April 2017, and, indeed, it did.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I understand, also, that there are matched slight kinks in the line showing that the orientation of the tunnel was adjusted to do just that.

Comment: You can post this question at [literature.se]

Comment: @BoldBen - yes, certain [reverse curves](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Railway-Engineering--Compound-and-Reverse-Curve_4228/).

Answer (score 7):

The normal meaning of "Could not see X for Y" is that Y is obscuring X and preventing you from seeing it. In this case eyes and mouth would not be literally obscuring the nose, so it is not a literal meaning. The next sentence indicates that women could describe, and so presumably see, the nose, and that "men" therefore probably means only males. Men and women see her differently.

Based on this we might deduce that the first sentence is related to sexual attraction. Probably the intended meaning is that the eyes and mouth so draw the attention of men that they never notice - never see - her nose.

Comment: And the other women "telling some nonsense" about this woman's nose are jealous and being catty.

Comment: Men would be **dazzled** by her eyes and mouth: women wouldn't.